# Short the uploaded pics and video url in wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I want to show the short url of the uploaded pics and videos to the users.if the users download the pics they don't get the actual path of the pics and videos.users could not know the actual location of the pics and videos. Please let me know the how can I do it in wordpress ? Is this possible in htaccess file?

For eg.
  http://example.com/images/pic.jpg

I want.

http://example.com/pic.jpg

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this, why do you need it?

Comment: I want to hide the exact location of the sources

Answer (score 0):

1. You must expose only the short URL. All of your links to these images but look like the `http://example.com/pic.jpg` form.
2. You can internally rewrite the `http://example.com/pic.jpg` to `/images/pic.jpg` by checking if such a file exists, then internally rewriting so the URL on the browser remains `http://example.com/pic.jpg` but they get served the image from `/images/pic.jpg`:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   # check that it's an image
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ [NC]
   # check that the resource actually exists in the /images/ directory
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images%{REQUEST_URI} -f
   # internally rewrite:
   RewriteRule ^ /images%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
   ```